# SSIS 2019 How to output nvarchar(max) column to flat file CSV UTF-8

Tags: sql-server, ssis

SSIS Visual Studio 2019 - Microsoft SQL Server 2019

I need to output using SSIS to a CSV UTF-8 file a SQL Server column which is nvarchar(max).

I have tried to convert but DT_WSTR has a 4,000 character limit and DT_STR 8,000.

Is there anyway to output data to CSV no matter the length of the column field?

Comment: Why not DT_NTEXT ?

Comment: Hi MD Zand - the current select from sql db has all columns coming in as Unicode string [DT_WSTR] except one the nvarchar(max) coming in as Unicode text stream [DT_NTEXT]

Comment: I have an odd error on the flat file connection 'The flat file connection is saying DT_NTEXT is not supported with ANSI' but the code page is set to 65001 (UTF-8)

Comment: if I tick the unicode box the package runs but when I check the file the encoding is: UCS-2 LE BOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting UTF-8 instead UCS-2 of you need to do this

In Source -> Advance Editor -> Component Properties ->  Set Default Code Page to 65001 AlwaysUseDefaultCodePage to True. Then Source->Advance Editor -> Input And OutPut Properties Check Each Column in External Columns and OutPut Columns and set CodePage to 65001 wherever possible.

Source: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a4854706-0d22-48c8-bc82-109630d23376/how-to-export-to-utf8bom-flat-file?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: Nice one Thanks MD Zand